# Grails3 java code can't be include in a project after migration from Grails2.x

Tags: java, gradle, configuration, grails3

I have a Grails project that works fine in `Grails 2.4.4`. I try to migrate it to `Grails 3.2.4`. But, I find a problem, when I try to import a java class in `application.grooy`, it says: 
 **can't locate the class**.
 I have put the all java code to `src/main/groovy.` And this directory is created by Grails for user to put java code. 
Do I need to do any config for it? I can't find instructions in document.

Comment: You may also show post the exact error message ( if any), to make it easier to answer

Answer (score 0):

How about putting all java code to `src/main/java`?